# Proper way to make a node app a service

Tags: ubuntu, service, upstart

I have a project folder with the app's contents, and to start it manually, I run `nohup npm start &` and then disown the proc.

I would like to figure out a way to make this a `service mynodeapp {start|stop|restart|etc}` command instead.

I am also aware that Ubuntu (and Debian in general) is deprecating the SysV init scripts and recommend upstart configs instead in `/etc/init/*.conf`.

How would I go about writing an upstart config with `start-stop-daemon`?

Thanks.

Comment: This document might help: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer this myself with the solution that worked best for me.

After digging around a bit, I just decided to undertake the burden of reading the upstart docs, and came up  with the following in `/etc/init/myapp.conf`:

```
# Node.js app config

description     "Node.js app upstart config"
author          "George K."

# Starting conditions
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)

# Stopping conditions
stop on shutdown

# If parent or any child exits, respawn
respawn

# The deed
script
    export HOME="/root"
    export WORKER_COUNT=4

    exec /usr/local/bin/node /path/to/app >> /var/log/app.log 2>&1
end script
```

Answer (score 1):

path: `/etc/init/myapp.conf`
make file executable with this command

```
chmod +x myapp.conf
```

`myapp.conf` source:

```
description "App Server"
author "Author"

start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

# if your app use port
env PORT=8080

chdir /home/domain/public_html/chat/
exec node index.js
```